# How does product catalog repository relate to inventory repository in ATG

Tags: repository, atg, inventory-management

If I create a SKU as a business user through BCC, the new sku created is updated in product catalog repository. Simlarly how does the update happens in Inventory repository. As in, how does product catalog interact with the inventory in ATG

Answer (score 1):

ProductCatalog and Inventory are two different repositories. They are not directly linked with each other in the way you might think.

/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog contains the sku item
/atg/commerce/inventory/Inventory has catalogRefId property that typically contains the sku_id of the sku from ProductCatalog. You can find it in the link here that defines Inventory repository properties (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGCommProgGuide/html/s1808inventoryrepository01.html)

Whenever you create a sku, an inventory item is created (through some customization) and the inventory levels is recorded in that item. You can ask developers to make inventory repository visible in BCC also with minimal customization so that you can look at sku as well as its inventory. There is also a dynamo admin tool where inventory can be managed and it can be found at this URL:

http://hostname:8080/dyn/admin/atg/commerce/admin/inventory/index.jhtml